# Invalid characters to test url

Tags: java

Here I have to take input URI from customer.
And base URL is - https://mydomain.com/router/

So, final URL will be - https://mydomain.com/router/<URI-from-customer>

Here I have to validate the final URL using -

```
java.net.URL url = new java.net.URL(finalURL);
```

But I was not able to test failure case. I tried with all the special characters but am not able to get malformed URL exception.

Following is the URI I tried with -

```
 维也纳恩斯特哈佩尔球场 &&& '";'><()!~`5%=-_}{}[]\||| ? ?&& / ?
```

Still there is no error.

So I want to know invalid characters to fail URL construction.

Comment: You can use the `URI` class instead of `URL`; it is much better at validation

Comment: what happens when you do openConnection?

Comment: @JunedAhsan Here I have to do format validation only. I don't want to open the connection to the URL.

Answer (score 0):

One way to trigger that `Exception` is with something like

```
String finalURL = "Like this";
try {
    java.net.URL url = new java.net.URL(finalURL);
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Output is (as requested)

> ```
> java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: Like this
>  at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:586)
>  at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:483)
>  at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:432)
>  at com.stackoverflow.Main.main(Main.java:15)
> ```